# How to send email without chooser dialog

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I send an email without chooser dialog using Intent. I removed `intent.settype()` from intent even though it shows chooser dialog. I want to show email page directly to Gmail or normal.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a